# Update values in a column except for when duplicates will be created

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a column that has values that begin with an apostrophe. I would like to update the table to remove the apostrophe from the front of the values that have it unless doing so will create a duplicate value. Ex: If I have a row with '456 and one with 456 I do not want to remove the apostrophe. I have this so far:

```
UPDATE part 
SET partnum = stuff(partnum, 1, 1, '')
WHERE left(partnum, 1) = ''''
```

How can I ensure that duplicates are not created? The values in this column vary in length.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not exists`:

```
UPDATE part
    SET partnum = stuff(partnum, 1, 1, '')
    WHERE partnum LIKE '''%' AND
          NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM part p2 WHERE '''' + p2.partnum = part.partnum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although Gordon's answer of a subquery and a NOT EXISTS condition is the most intuitive solution, you can alternatively use an OUTER JOIN to check for duplicates, improving the performance over a correlated subquery.

```
UPDATE part 
SET partnum = stuff(part.partnum, 1, 1, '')
FROM part 
     LEFT JOIN part as duplicate on duplicate.partnum = stuff(part.partnum, 1, 1, '') 
WHERE left(part.partnum, 1) = '''' and
      duplicate.partnum is null
```